Laravel eager and lazy loading at the same time
I am wondering what is happening when you preload relationships and also use lazy to stream data.
For example:
$query = User::query()
    ->where('age', '>=', 18)
    ->with([
        'posts' => ['images'],
        'comments'
    ]);

foreach($query->lazy(1000) as $user) {
  // do stuff with preloaded data
}

How is the with statement behaving in this case? Is it only preloading for the 1000 chunk?

Each chunk will do its own queries.
To illustrate I'll simplify your example by only considering the User and Post models (User has many Post / Post belongs to User).
Let's say there are only 13 users in the database (ids 1 through 13)
The following code:
$query = User::with('posts')->orderBy('id');

foreach ($query->lazy(5) as $user) {
    echo $user->id . "\n";
}

Would do the following
// query select * from users order by id asc limit 5 offset 0
// query select * from posts where user_id in (1,2,3,4,5)
1
2
3
4
5
// query select * from users order by id asc limit 5 offset 5
// query select * from posts where user_id in (6,7,8,9,10)
6
7
8
9
10
// query select * from users order by id asc limit 5 offset 10
// query select * from posts where user_id in (11,12,13)
11
12
13


If you want to see this for yourself, you can use DB::listen to help. I did it in the artisan console
DB::listen(fn ($query) => dump($query->sql));

$query = User::with('posts')->orderBy('id');

foreach ($query->lazy(5) as $user) {
    dump($user->id);
}

